# "Don't even get me nests than the client admitted to"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I'm trying to understand this phrase. What does it mean? Is it even grammatically correct?

Context:

> "How was the hunt though? Worth it?" the blond countered.
>
> "**Don't even get me nests than the client admitted to**, gore everywhere,
>   and a pittance in payment." the lady hunter ranted and went into more
>   detail.

<sub>This appears to be a quote from fanfiction.net. Lady Monotogari's *Her Day*. https://www.fanfiction.net/s/4796968/1/Her-Day-Lady</sub>

Comment: No idea. ***Nests than*** sounds wrong. Could this be a mishearing for  different words?

Comment: Is this text or speech?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mishear **less than**? That's the only thing that would seem to make sense.

Comment: It's a text. I think it might be a typo. But I can't think of a typo that would make it correct.

Comment: I've added what could be the original source of the quote. It is a standard on this site to attribute all quoted material (including images). The standards for attribution can be found here http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4981/71783.

Comment: Having looked over the link Frank provided, I think it's safe to say that anything in the story you don't understand can probably be attributed to typos, grammatical errors, or the author's lack of familiarity with storytelling conventions and/or the sexual act.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I submit this for your consideration ...

> "Don't *even* get me **less** than the client **committed** to, gore everywhere, and a pittance in payment." the lady hunter ranted and went into more detail.

Would mean ...

**Don't accept less money than was agreed upon - all this mess - and for almost no profit**

Does that make sense, in context?

Comment: Nice going, LE! Don

Comment: Sounds right. It is a mishearing, texted or no.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that there were multiple words missing in the print/translation of this?

> "How was the hunt though? Worth it?" the blond countered.
>
> "Don't even get me **started. Less** nests than the client admitted to, gore everywhere, and a pittance in payment." the lady hunter ranted and went into more detail.

Comment: Depending on the context, I'd suspect that *more* nests was more likely, but still this seems very feasible.

Comment: As it sounded like the hunter was disappointed, I assumed less nests would be a closer fit than more as it would be less likely it would be a successful hunt. Unless, of course, the hunter is a reluctant hunter (hunting something they're afraid of) in which case I think you'd be right.

Comment: My thought, based on the minimal context, is that the client did more damage than they'd said (they destroyed "more nests than [they] admitted to"), made a huge mess ("gore everywhere"), and as a result the actual profit was negligible ("a pittance in payment").  Perhaps the lady hunter is in charge of making sure that the nests are accessible and have prey available?